# How to make scoverage work with multi-project that are not located on the same project-root?

Tags: scala, sbt, scoverage

I work with a multi-project structure in scala. Some of the projects are located outside the root-project. There is a simlink to link them and make sbt works. Here is a small example of the structure:

some-project

root-folder/some-project -> ../some-project

The problem is: scoverage doesn't work with these projects, causing the coverage to be wrong.

When I run the command 'sbt reportCoverage' I get this kind of error:

> [error] (scalaCommons/*:coverageReport) No source root found for '/Users/user1/dev/root-folder/some-project...